# Series about robots made of metal and plants, which are fought by a small group of humans

Tags: story-identification, cartoon

I watched a few episodes of this cartoon a few years ago. All I can remember about it are as follows:

- there are these bad robots that are part metal, part plant
- the good guys travel to several planets in a sailing ship-like spaceship
- the main character (male) is looking for his father

Does anyone know what the name of this series is?

Comment: how would it be a duplicate?

Comment: The policy on `story-identification` questions is that if they have the same accepted answer, they're duplicates.

Comment: https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3431/why-would-vtc-as-duplicate-be-appropriate-for-a-story-identification-question FWIW

Comment: So, do you feel that this does match?

Comment: haven't really thought about it, but it feels like it might be it

Comment: :) No rush, really, but I felt like I accidentally derailed things by bringing up the dupe situation. FWIW, the episodes are pretty easy to find on YouTube.

Comment: you know, I actually think this is it. Thank you for helping me

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*[Jayce and the Wheeled Warriors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jayce_and_the_Wheeled_Warriors)*

[image: Cover image for *Jayce and the Wheeled Warriors*]

> The series follows protagonists Jayce, Flora, Herc Stormsailor, Oon, and Gillian in their search for Jayce's father Audric. Meanwhile, they are opposing the main antagonist Saw Boss and his followers, the Monster Minds. Audric was a botanist who performed experiments with biotechnology, one experiment creating Flora. In another experiment, Audric attempted to create a plant that could prevent starvation. But when he succeeded, a nearby star exploded into a supernova. The radiation from the supernova's explosion changed the plant and four others into the Monster Minds: a race of plant-like monsters who wish to conquer the universe. Audric created a root that could destroy the Monster Minds, but was forced to flee before he could complete the task, after which the Monster Minds made Audric's laboratory their headquarters. Audric kept half of the root himself and gave the other half to his servant, the Eternal Squire Oon, whom he sent to serve Jayce. Jayce and his friends are thereafter on a quest to find Audric and form the complete root.

Yes, Herc Stormsailor's ship, The Pride of the Skies II, looked very much like a conventional sailing ship:
[image: Image of The Pride of the Skies II]

### Opening Credits

I think I watched only one or two episodes as a kid, but I had one of the toys and some of my neighborhood friends had others. The key "innovation" involved a lot of hardpoint sockets where you could attach the weapon parts, which were pretty universally interchangeable (and were even offered as their own individual packages of accessories). However, toy sales were not sufficient and so the series was cancelled with 65 episodes and an unfilmed movie script by J. Michael Straczynski.